# Calendar + Tag Sortable Scheduling Software

Tags: calendar, microsoft-excel, scheduling

I'm looking for a scheduling application with specific features.

Here's the situation: My job requires me to call students once every two weeks. I schedule with the students when we are in class sometimes so I need to be able to easily show them my current schedule (including any already scheduled calls) on a calendar in class so we can easily pick out a time to call.

Google calendar is adequate for that but here's what it doesn't provide:

I need to be able to easily see which students have been scheduled for a particular call topic and which students have not been scheduled. I should also be able to sort the students by any number of details such as the class group they belong to, their name, etc. Additionally, I want to be able to quickly see how many days apart calls to the same student were.

As an example, here is what my Gcal and my Excel sheet look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccNj2.jpg The only down side is I'm having to manually reenter everything into the Excel sheet and that takes a long time. Isn't there some sort of software that can allow me to easily schedule the calls and easily sort by the information in my columns?

Thanks for any advice. I'm sick of spending so much time entering data when I should be working on lesson planning.

Comment: Are you using a cell phone to make the calls?  You can install an app that logs the call with caller id, time,date, and duration to google calendar.  If you enter all their names into your address book then their names should appear automatically.  Maybe add different calendars for each call topic.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not, but that's a good idea.